# Web mining -classification algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, mining

my senior project is determining the dominant category of a web page.I crawled dmoz. now i am trying to build arff. After that i will use some feature extraction methods and classification algorithms. Do you know which feature extraction method performs good with any classification algorithm for web mining?

Answer (score 3):

**[uClassify](http://www.uclassify.com/)** uses **[Bayesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) [Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network)** and claims to be able to categorize web pages.

uClassify is a free web service where you can easily create your own text classifiers. Examples:

- Spam filter
- **Web page categorization**
- Automatic e-mail support
- Language detection
- Written text gender recognition
- Mood
- Sentiment